# Is there a way to fetch all transactions in a block via electrum protocol?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, electrum

Quickly surfing through the list of electrum methods, looks like not, and I will have to use `getblock` from bitcoind json-rpc.
Is there a better way?

Comment: Looping for all: [`blockchain.transaction.id_from_pos`](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html#blockchain-transaction-id-from-pos)?

Comment: thanks @MCCCS that looks like what I need! is there a way to get how many transactions there are in a specific block (without iterating to some ridiculous value like 99999)?

Comment: No I don't think that's possible, you need to iterate (though you can check like 1,2,4,8,...512,1024) then binary bisect